# How to achieve WPF Docking function as Visual Studio Docking function

Tags: wpf

Is there any docking library available in C# WPF, which i can call and achieve the Docking Window functionality?
Or should i write the full code for achieving docking window functionality, which i dont know how would i do. 
I read about the third party docking control which i dont want to use.
Also i heard about AvalonDock, can someone suggest how should i achieve docking functionality using Avalon Dock or any other library?
I am new to C#, dont have much experience but trying hard to learn this feature. Any direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a tutorial on this. Have a look at it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439873/Simple-Visual-Studio-like-Pane-Resizing-Docking-an